# Android Alarm Manager with Kivy not working

Tags: python, android, service, kivy, alarmmanager

I am trying to run a service, declared in buildozer.spec with Alarm Manager, but unfortunately it throws an error. I need Alarm Manager in order to schedule my service to run every day.

Let me just get to the point. I have this simple service in Buildozer that just makes few requests to my api:

```
    from time import sleep
    
    url = "some/url"
    
    while True:
        requests.get(url)
        sleep(30)
```

And a simple Kivy app that runs this service in the 'on_start' function:

```
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    
    class MainApp(MDApp):
        def on_start(self):
            if platform == "android":
                self.service_start()
        def service_start(self):
            from jnius import autoclass
            service = autoclass("org.my.app.ServiceMyservice")
            mActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity").mActivity
            service.start(mActivity, "")
            return service
```

Obviously I have 'build' function and everything else set up so the app runs and with it, the service.

Now I would like to run the service forever or at least once a day, so I increase the 'sleep', but Android stops it after one loop. Therefore, I am trying to use Android Alarm Manager to schedule the service each day, but am failing to do so. I tried it like so:

```
    def on_start(self):
            from jnius import autoclass
            service = autoclass("org.my.app.ServiceMyservice")
            #get activtiy
            activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
            #get manager
            AlarmManager = autoclass('android.app.AlarmManager')
            alarm_manager = activity.getSystemService(activity.ALARM_SERVICE)
            
            PendingIntent = autoclass('android.app.PendingIntent')
            Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
            
    
            
            interval = 86400 * 1000 #   1day
            request_code = 0
            intent = Intent(activity, service)
            pending_intent = PendingIntent.getService(activity, request_code, intent, 0)
            alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, interval, pending_intent)
            return alarm_manager
```

And I've changed my service from a while loop to a function, but it throws the following java error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.my.app.ServiceMyservice@7c59518 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=org.my.app/.ServiceMyservice (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Here is the relevant part of my log. It starts the main loop and the service, but it immediately crashes. The GUI is unaffected, it just says the service has stopped running on android device.

```
01-05 22:53:11.159  1663    1878    system_server   I   ActivityManager Start proc 13900:org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni/u0a404 for service {org.dasadweb.eamenu/org.dasadweb.eamenu.ServiceMeni}
01-05 22:53:11.164  1362    1412    adbd    I   adbd    jdwp connection from 13899
01-05 22:53:11.164  13900   13900   No info available   I   libc    SetHeapTaggingLevel: tag level set to 0
01-05 22:53:11.164  13899   13899   No info available   D   ProcessState    Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
01-05 22:53:11.169  1663    12867   system_server   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 168419799; UID 10291; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:11.170  13900   13900   No info available   I   nu:service_Men  Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-05 22:53:11.174  13899   13899   No info available   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10291; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:11.181  13899   13899   No info available   D   ApplicationLoaders  Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
01-05 22:53:11.204  1362    1412    adbd    I   adbd    jdwp connection from 13900
01-05 22:53:11.206  13900   13900   No info available   D   ProcessState    Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
01-05 22:53:11.234  13900   13900   No info available   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10404; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:11.239  13899   13899   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE Developer option for 'com.google.android.apps.authenticator2' set to: 'default'
01-05 22:53:11.240  13899   13899   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE GameManagerService for com.google.android.apps.authenticator2: false
01-05 22:53:11.241  13899   13899   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
01-05 22:53:11.242  13900   13900   No info available   D   ApplicationLoaders  Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
01-05 22:53:11.242  13899   13899   No info available   D   NetworkSecurityConfig   No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-05 22:53:11.243  13899   13899   No info available   D   NetworkSecurityConfig   No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-05 22:53:11.245  13899   13899   No info available   I   MultiDex    VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
01-05 22:53:11.245  13899   13899   No info available   I   MultiDex    install
01-05 22:53:11.245  13899   13899   No info available   I   MultiDex    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
01-05 22:53:11.259  13900   13900   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE Developer option for 'org.dasadweb.eamenu' set to: 'default'
01-05 22:53:11.259  13900   13900   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE GameManagerService for org.dasadweb.eamenu: false
01-05 22:53:11.260  13900   13900   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
01-05 22:53:11.262  13900   13900   No info available   D   NetworkSecurityConfig   No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-05 22:53:11.263  13900   13900   No info available   D   NetworkSecurityConfig   No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-05 22:53:11.267  13900   13900   No info available   D   AndroidRuntime  Shutting down VM
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  Process: org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni, PID: 13900
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.dasadweb.eamenu.ServiceMeni@7c59518 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=org.dasadweb.eamenu/.ServiceMeni (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4724)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:256)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2129)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at org.kivy.android.PythonService.onStartCommand(PythonService.java:82)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4706)
01-05 22:53:11.268  13900   13900   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      ... 9 more
01-05 22:53:11.271  1663    13934   system_server   I   DropBoxManagerService   add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
01-05 22:53:11.273  13900   13900   No info available   I   Process Sending signal. PID: 13900 SIG: 9
01-05 22:53:11.279  1663    1882    system_server   I   libprocessgroup Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10404 pid 13900 in 0ms
01-05 22:53:11.279  1663    12867   system_server   I   ActivityManager Process org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni (pid 13900) has died: fg  SVC 
01-05 22:53:11.280  1011    1011    zygote64    I   Zygote  Process 13900 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
01-05 22:53:11.280  1663    12867   system_server   W   ActivityManager Scheduling restart of crashed service org.dasadweb.eamenu/.ServiceMeni in 1000ms for start-requested
01-05 22:53:11.281  29928   12525   com.google.android.gms  D   GmsServicesProvider query caller=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2 name=primes:shutdown_primes value=false
01-05 22:53:11.350  29928   29928   com.google.android.gms  D   ClearcutLoggerService   onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.clearcut.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
01-05 22:53:11.354  29928   9504    com.google.android.gms  D   ClearcutLoggerService   bound by: GetServiceRequest{serviceId=CLEARCUT_LOGGER, gmsVersion=201802000, packageName='com.google.android.apps.authenticator2', extras=Bundle[{}]}
01-05 22:53:12.284  1663    1877    system_server   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 135634846; UID 10404; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:12.285  1663    1877    system_server   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 177438394; UID 10404; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:12.285  1663    1877    system_server   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 135772972; UID 10404; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:12.285  1663    1877    system_server   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 135754954; UID 10404; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:12.286  1663    1878    system_server   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 143937733; UID 10404; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:12.298  1011    1011    zygote64    D   Zygote  Forked child process 13941
01-05 22:53:12.299  1663    1878    system_server   I   ActivityManager Start proc 13941:org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni/u0a404 for service {org.dasadweb.eamenu/org.dasadweb.eamenu.ServiceMeni}
01-05 22:53:12.304  13941   13941   No info available   I   libc    SetHeapTaggingLevel: tag level set to 0
01-05 22:53:12.307  13941   13941   No info available   I   nu:service_Men  Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-05 22:53:12.329  1362    1412    adbd    I   adbd    jdwp connection from 13941
01-05 22:53:12.331  13941   13941   No info available   D   ProcessState    Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
01-05 22:53:12.361  13941   13941   No info available   D   CompatibilityChangeReporter Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10404; state: DISABLED
01-05 22:53:12.378  13941   13941   No info available   D   ApplicationLoaders  Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
01-05 22:53:12.420  13941   13941   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE Developer option for 'org.dasadweb.eamenu' set to: 'default'
01-05 22:53:12.421  13941   13941   No info available   V   GraphicsEnvironment ANGLE GameManagerService for org.dasadweb.eamenu: false
01-05 22:53:12.421  13941   13941   org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni    V   GraphicsEnvironment Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
01-05 22:53:12.427  13941   13941   org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni    D   NetworkSecurityConfig   No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-05 22:53:12.429  13941   13941   org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni    D   NetworkSecurityConfig   No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-05 22:53:12.441  13941   13941   org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni    D   AndroidRuntime  Shutting down VM
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  Process: org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni, PID: 13941
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.dasadweb.eamenu.ServiceMeni@7c59518 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=org.dasadweb.eamenu/.ServiceMeni (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4724)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:256)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2129)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   No info available   E   AndroidRuntime      at org.kivy.android.PythonService.onStartCommand(PythonService.java:82)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni    E   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4706)
01-05 22:53:12.444  13941   13941   org.dasadweb.eamenu:service_Meni    E   AndroidRuntime      ... 9 more
01-05 22:53:12.450  1663    13961   system_server   I   DropBoxManagerService   add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
01-05 22:53:12.511  13474   13474   org.dasadweb.eamenu V   SDL onWindowFocusChanged(): false
01-05 22:53:12.511  13474   13474   org.dasadweb.eamenu V   SDL nativePause()
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way of doing it? Every answer is appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace or point to where exactly in the code this error is coming from?

Comment: I'll have to run the app on computer once I get home. I'll update the post then.

Comment: @tomerpacific - Thank you for such fast response! I have updated the post with the relevant part of the log. If bigger section of it is needed, I can provide it, but everything else runs fine.

Comment: I would advise you to debug your code (with breakpoints) to see which lines throws the exception. Then you will know where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @tomerpacific I found some new errors in the logs, mind taking a look? Thank you for your time :)